# Access the sass variable from a different folder Vue JS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

i've tried to create component `ButtonFilled.vue` and i want to styling sass on this component and access the sass variable like this

[image]

but i qot this error, any solution?
[image]

this is my `main.js` file

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

import "@/assets/sass/master.sass";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

this is my `master.sass`

```
// Base
@import "./base/fonts"
@import "./base/resets"
@import "./base/typography"

// Abstracts
@import "./abstracts/variables"
@import "./abstracts/functions"
@import "./abstracts/mixins"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use this on `vue.config.js` and its works, thanks all

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `@import "~@/assets/sass/abstracts/variables.sass";`
      }
    }
  }
}
```